# hide and show a panel on button click c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating an application with one panel my aim is when the page loads the panel should be invisible and on a button click show panel and also be able to hide it with the same button on click. i was able to achieve showing it when one clicks the button, now i'm trying to hide it again on a button click.

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
} 

public void hidePanels() {
    panel2.Visible = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    hidePanels();
} 

private void button1Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    hidePanels();
    panel2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible

Comment: `panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible `, to set the visible property to the opposite of what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, set your panel visibility property to false in the property panel.

In order to hide or show your panel you can use this code :

```
  private void button1Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible;
  }
```

Comment: Your wellcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
                if (panel2.Visible)
                    panel2.Visible = false;
                else
                    panel2.Visible = true;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much info. Assuming you are using .net -

**Your .aspx page should look like this -**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" OnClick="btnHide_Click"></asp:Button>
```

**Code behind will look like this -**

**To hide the panel on page load -**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = false;
}
```

**To show the content on button click -**

```
protected void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(panel2.Visible) 
       panel2.Visible= false;
    else
       panel2.Visible= true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to hide your panel(s), the `first way` is you can set the property of the panel to false and the `second way` is you can put it in your form load.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  panel2.Visible = false;
}

private void button1Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  panel2.Visible = true;
}
```